# How to build a Saas service which send some emails on behalf of your clients?

Tags: email, smtp, saas

So this is not at all the focus of the Saas service, but a small needed component.

Lets call the domain myservice.com, and I have a client MacDonalds.
I want (MacDonalds) users to able to send emails from the service to customers, and I think the best way is not to try to get smtp access to all the different clients SMTP systems (as some are small clients just using gmail etc), so I'm thinking I have outgoing emails from my server e.g.

```
From: MacDonalds System123 <macdonalds@myservice.com> 
Reply-to: contactus@macdonalds.com
```

Is this the best way to do this? - I can see it would be a huge headache to have to get smtp details for each client, and then possibly some process to regularly check the details are valid (and the client hasn't accidentally updated their password etc).